# iOS 10 notification in background after terminated the app?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios10

How to store a payload notification object in database when application is terminated by user. Any delegate methods is call when app is terminated by user so I can store a  payload notification object in database when notification is come.

Comment: You should not rely on notification being delivered; even if the app isn't terminated delivery is not guaranteed.  The first thing your app should do when it starts is check with your server for updated data.

Comment: As @Paulw11 said, notifications are not guaranteed to be delivered. There's no way to do what you're asking, but if your goal is to make sure the user sees important notifications the next time they launch the app (or that a remote payload is delivered to your app), then you should store those in a server-side database and request any new ones at app launch. Push notifications might not be delivered, they might not be seen, they might be ignored, or they might be viewed but never "tapped through" to your app.

Comment: okay understand , Problem is this when I am getting a multiple notification on background  mode when I click on a particular notification , rest of notification data is not track.

For example :- hope you are using watsaap , when you terminated your watsapp application then you will get multiple notification when you click on a particular notification you redirect on the watsaap chat window and all rest message is also show on that , so I just want to implementing this functionality by using fire base.

Comment: WhatsApp will check there server when you start the app and pull down all the pending messages

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Notification Service Extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension). It will be call when you receive a notification (even if the app is terminated) containing the entry

- `"mutable-content" : 1`

Once the service is launched. You store the payload in your database.

Comment: Getting Notification from FCM so not able to get this key "mutable-content" : 1.

Comment: Actually you can (did you search?), go to [Notification Composer](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/notification/compose) and in **Advanced Options** you can set a key/value